# Setting variable equal to if statement condition

Tags: swift, if-statement, var

I have an if statement that checks to see if an array element matches a local variable.

```
 if pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title == restaurantName})
```

How would I create a variable of this element? 
I attempted

```
 let thePin = pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title == restaurantName})
```

but this comes with "could not cast boolean to MKAnnotation".

I also tried variations of

```
let pins = [pinArray.indexPath.row]
let pinn = pins(where: pin.title == restaurantName) (or close to it)

mapp.selectAnnotation(thePin as! MKAnnotation, animated: true)
```

to no avail. What basic step am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If you actually have code such as `if pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title == restaurantName}) { // some stuff }` then you can definitely replace that with `let thePin = pinArray.contains(where: {$0.title == restaurantName})` followed by `if thePin { // some stuff }`.

Comment: Happen to see anything in the update that is causing the signal sibart?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as text.

Comment: Why are you attempting to force-cast a `Bool` to a `MKAnnotation`? `thePin` is a `Bool` indicating whether the array contains the value or not.

Comment: I was attempting to create a variable that is equal to the pin of the pinArray that is equal to/has the same title as restaurantName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains(where:)` returns a `Bool` indicating whether a match was found or not. It does not return the matched value.

So `thePin` is a `Bool` which you then attempt to force-cast to a `MKAnnotation` which of course crashes.

If you want the matching value, change your code to:

```
if let thePin = pinArray.first(where: { $0.title == restaurantName }) {
    do {
        mapp.selectionAnnotation(thePin, animated: true)
    } catch {
    }
} else {
    // no match in the array
}
```

No need for `contains` at all. No need to cast (assuming `pinArray` is an array of `MKAnnotation`).

Comment: I have to ask, you've helped me throughout several projects - thanks, haha - but how have you come to know so much?  Also, in the if let statement, "first" refers to the first element that matches restaurantName?

Comment: Yes, it's the first match. See the documentation for [first(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first). And I've been programming since 1979.